# Implement generic table component using mudblazor with in blazor app. .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, laravel-blade, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnlIw.png)how to create a dynamic table  template using mudblazor in blazor application.
table can be generic. i don't see much resource in internet. Can some one help me.

i am trying to create reusable component of mudtable.which takes list or datatable as input.it is generic component. it takes different input sourses.

Comment: Did you look at their examples https://mudblazor.com/components/table

Comment: yes sir. I am looking for generic one. the above link gives idea on mutable. I am looking for generic mud table sample.@BenRubin

Comment: If you want a table that you can populate yourself similar to an HTML table, use MudSimpleTable https://mudblazor.com/components/simpletable

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @BenRubin can we customize rowtemplete in mudblazer ?.  i have to create a template that used by another application. I saw that row template iterates through items. but i need to over ride the functionality. is there any way ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Could you update your question to show a simple example of what you're looking for?

Comment: i have added screen shot.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you make your own custom component with MudBlazor:

CESimpleTable.razor

```html
<MudSimpleTable>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th>Text</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach(var note in List) {
            <tr>
                <td>@note.Author</td>
                <td>@note.Text</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</MudSimpleTable>

@code {
    [Parameter] public List<Note> List { get; set; }
}
```

We used MudSimpleTable here, but you can also use MudTable.

We are using a class Note for demonstration purposes:

Note.cs

```cs
    public class Note {
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
```

and finally how to use your CESimpleTable:

```html
<h1>
    My own simple table component
</h1>

<CESimpleTable List="_notes"/>

@code {


    List<Note> _notes = new List<Note>() {
        new Note { Author="Henon", Text="How awesome is MudBlazor?" },
        new Note { Author="Ben Rubin", Text="Howdy!" },
    };

}
```

This is how it looks like:

[image: a custom component with MudBlazor]

You can play around with this solution on try.mudblazor.com: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wkQbPPbgheBvuPxq